# What are the good options for connecting Microsoft Outlook to a Yahoo email account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, outlook-express, windows-live-mail, yahoo-mail

I have used ypops in the past.   I think that was a sort-of community-provided software that violated the Terms of service of Yahoo Mail.

Has anything changed? Are there better options?

This is for a friend of mine, who needs some help.

I like the Microsoft Outlook user interface. I like the management for email folders, contacts, and address lists.  I like the ability to do offline composition, and scheduled sends. I like the calendaring. All of these things are going to be useful for this friend of mine.

I don't use Yahoo Mail myself, so I'm not sure how Outlook 2007 compares with the web interface available for Yahoo Mail, or other alternative UIs for Yahoo Mail. Does the web interface have that kind of stuff?  I assume not.

I know that Hotmail integrates nicely with ... it used to be Outlook Express?  now I think the client-side software is called Windows Live Mail.  Is there a possibility to do something like that with Yahoo and a "rich" email client?

Is this what I need?  [Yahoo Mail plus](http://overview.mail.Yahoo.com/enhancements/mailplus)?  Seems like not a lot of money for the capability.

Comment: Is there any reason your friend has to use YMail? How about forwarding all his Yahoo mail to Gmail?

Comment: only reason is he is already on yahoo mail, and has been for "years" I guess. I wanted minimal disruption for him.